# How to handle git ftp when init was done with wrong directory

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I had a misspelling in my .git/config file to use with git-ftp

**.git/config**

```
[git-ftp]
    user = myuser
    url = ftp.myhosting.com/myFtpFolderForSiteMispelled
    password = ****************
```

**Steps I did that got me to this question**

- My local repo was a brand new git repo with files that were the same as the FTP.
- Made some minor changes to the local repo and committed
- Setup the .git/config with the FTP Info that pointed to a nonexistent (wrong) directory but did not know this at the time.
- ran: git ftp init
- ran: git ftp push
- Checked the live website and did not see the changes present
- Found what I did wrong with the config URL pointing to a non-existent folder.
- git ftp init created the wrong folder on my init and uploaded all the files there.

I'm fairly new to git so I have stopped until I can get some help here so I don't make matters worse.  Haven't been able to find anything about this specific issue anywhere.

The files in my local repo are correct.  I could manually upload to the FTP and get those files in sync or not depending on advice given here.

Question is:  How do I remove the git ftp info from my local repo and start with a fresh git ftp init or other methodology to fix this.

Other question: should I have initialized my FTP repo (git ftp init) prior to making changes to my local files, or was I okay to make those changes then run the git ftp init followed by the push.  My thought was the local repo ruled the day so when I would run a git ftp push it would update the FTP (remote repo) to match the local master.

Thanks as always!
 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Here is what I would do.

Assuming that you still have a git repo, that you are not using `git ftp` with at the moment, because of the error in the config file.

Navigate to your server, via file-zilla or some other GUI so you can see what your doing.

- Find where "git ftp init created the wrong folder on my init and
  uploaded all the files there." --and delete all of those files.
- Now assuming that you have still been making changes to the website, and using a different ftp client, its it important to sync all of the working files on your server with your local git repo. So download all of the files from your server repo, into your local git repo. -- if you are following along with what I'm getting at, `git status` should return a bunch of changed files at this point.
- Now you should be ready to modify your `.git/config` file to the correct path, any text editor will do, I like vi
- After all that is done you should be able to run a successful `git ftp init`
- After that is done, any other changes will require a `git ftp push` to push to your server. I would recommend using bitbucket/github to host your code for your everyday `git pull` and `git push` , and then use `git ftp push` to push those files to a remote server.